# Net 4.0 Wpf UserControl Library- Can it be referenced in a VS 2008 Package ToolWindow

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008-sp1, vs-extensibility

I have a project to build an Extensibility Package with a toolwindow using a WPF UserControl Library.  I have VS 2008 and VS 2010 versions.  Reusing the Wpf for both versions is easy to do if I keep the Net framework to 3.5 or less.  There is an existing Silverlight 4.0/Net 4.0 application that I have been asked to convert to the WPF. It uses a lot of the 4.0 features and reworking it to a less version is major work.  I have run tests to try using Net 4.0 Wpf and the VS 2008 Package refuses to recognize the reference.

My question is this: Is using Wpf Net 4.0 in a VS 2008 Package doable in any way?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the VisualStudio Team is- No, no hacks, no round about, no way